# How to draw a line in windows which fill width in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window which is its size can be change during run time by user.

I want to draw a horizontal line which extends to the width of window.

I can do this by code behind (on window resize event, change the size of line),

but  am looking for a way to change the size of line in xaml, so for example bind x1,x2,y1 and y2 to their parents (or window) size in a way that line resize itself when the size of window changes.

How can I do this?

Comment: `<Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="1"/>` = all ya need, or set width=1 for vertical.

Comment: @ChrisW.  That won't work in a Canvas or WrapPanel though.

Comment: @WaltRitscher Thanks, he specified a Window, not the panel. Was just trying to keep it as easy/simple as possible. However thanks for the clarification for the OP

Answer (score 17):

In this case, the maybe try use [`Separator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A `Separator` control draws a *line*, horizontal or vertical, between items in controls, such as ListBox, Menu, and ToolBar.

For Separator base class is `Control`, this means that it is possible to apply a Style/ControlTemplate, that is comfortable when you want stored separately properties for him.

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Separator Name="MySeparator" 
               Height="4"
               Width="Auto"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"                   
               Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

This example draws a line in bottom on the entire Width of the `Window`. Setting properties `Width="Auto"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` can automatically stretch Separator at the Width of the Window.

To specify an arbitrary `Height` for Separator, use the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Note that in UWP, the Separator control is not available.

Answer (score 15):

This draws a line the width of the Window, regardless of which `Panel` you choose. (`Canvas, Grid, StackPanel`, etc.).

It also works if you need a line that is not parallel to the Window top.

*// Assumes the Window is named MainWindow*

**XAML**

```
<Canvas>
    <Line X1='0'
          X2='{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
               AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}'
          Y1='50'
          Y2='90'
          Stroke="Orange"
          StrokeThickness='2' />

   <Line X1='0'
         X2='{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
              AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}'
          Y1='110' 
          Y2='110'
          Stroke="Green"
          StrokeThickness='2' />

  </Canvas>
```

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]